# Why is only UIKit.Framework imported in the header files? Why not the other default frameworks, e.g. Foundation framework?

Tags: iphone, ios

I actually get confused some times about why we find only " #import  " in all the header files that we create? And again why are we provided only 3 frameworks(Foundation, UIKit,CoreGraphics) when we create any iPhone Application?

Comment: It's a default project template of xcode. Create your own project template.

Comment: The title and question seams to be two different questions? But if you look in `UIKit/UIKit.h` you will see that it imports a lots of UIKit stuff and most of them, like `UIButton.h`, will import `Foundation/Foundation.h` by them self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least when starting a new project from xcode templates, the PreCompiled Headers (.pch) contains

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

so actually, no imports of those two would be required anywhere else.

I tend to drop

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

from all my source files and just keep the implicit one via the .pch file.

Answer (score 3):

UIKit requires Foundation, so it imports it itself. If you import UIKit, you get Foundation for free. Also, as Christoph says, your .pch causes all your files to import Foundation anyway.

In terms of being provided with three frameworks, you can link against whichever ones you like: look in the Target Settings for your app (top item on the left hand sidebar (named after your project), then click on your Target in the next column, then click the Build Phases tab):

[image: Link with libraries section]

Just click the Add button below the list, and you can choose whatever framework you want.